# Jenkinsfile - timed (cron) trigger only if changes detected

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile.

I would like to do a nightly build (at let's say midnight), but only if changes were detected since the previous build.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
        pollSCM('H */4 * * 1-5')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As per the Jenkins documentation, `pollSCM` does the following:

> Accepts a cron-style string to define a regular interval at which
>   Jenkins should check for new source changes. If new changes exist, the
>   Pipeline will be re-triggered.

There's a more complicated way to accomplish same behaviour (just an alternative to `pollSCM`), that is putting a normal cron:

```
triggers {
    cron('H */4 * * 1-5')
}
```

And then checking for changes with the environment variables:

```
stage('Example') {
    when {
       expression {
           !env.currentBuild.changeSets.isEmpty()
       }
    }
    steps {
        echo 'Hello World'
    }
}
```

Also per the docs, `env.currentBuild.changeSets`:

> This is a list of changesets coming from distinct SCM checkouts; each
>   has a kind and is a list of commits; each commit has a commitId,
>   timestamp, msg, author, and affectedFiles each of which has an
>   editType and path; the value will not generally be Serializable so you
>   may only access it inside a method marked @NonCPS

Reference:

- https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/
- https://opensource.triology.de/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals